# Google Drive open password protected PDF file in WebView

Tags: javascript, vb4android

I am trying to open in WebView Google Drive hosted PDF file  which is password protected.
Here is the file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vzlf7OcMwIN_yLmgAqOUK1BOjTqS2DSI/view?usp=share_link)

So, after page load finished, using following java script command I'm injecting password to password input.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-UmsTj-YPqjbf')[0].value = '123456'
```

But I am struggling to emulate "SUBMIT" button press. What java script command should I use to emulate SUBMIT button click?

I have tried this commands, but it didn't  work

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-UmsTj-YPqjbf')[0].focus()
document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-UmsTj-YPqjbf')[0].click()
```

Comment: I have tried that way. but I am not sure that it is a good solution

Comment: How to add 7th key as enter in one line command?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-UmsTj-YPqjbf')[0].value = '123456' + chars(13) ?